# Calling Firebase DatabaseReferenc method UpdateChildren() throws Stack Overflow Error when called from RecyclerView onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-recyclerview

I am currently executing these code in my recyclerView onBindViewholder, but I am getting stack overflow.

```
final DatabaseReference ref = getRef(position);
//update the uploaded node
final HashMap<String, Object> fullUploadUpdate = new HashMap<>();
fullUploadUpdate.put("uploaded", true);
StorageTask<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> t1 = thumbUploadRef.putBytes(ImageUtils.compressImage(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), filePath), 20))
.addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        fullUploadUpdate.put("thumbnailUri", taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl());

    }
});
StorageTask<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> t2 = fullUploadRef.putFile(filePath)
.addOnProgressListener(getActivity(), new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
        Timber.d("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
        mpOutHolder.setUploadProgress(progress);
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        fullUploadUpdate.put("fullImageUri", taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl());
        fullUploadUpdate.put("size", taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
    }
});

Tasks.whenAll(t1, t2).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        ref.updateChildren(fullUploadUpdate);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the HasMap i need to call 
 `taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString()`